# What does exchangevent indicate in SQL deadlock graph?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, deadlock-graph

Have a deadlock XDL file with several exchange events listed.  Not sure if these are good or bad or what causes them.  What causes exchange events in SQL deadlock graph?

```xml
 <exchangeEvent id="Pipe12dfb4bc900" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" nodeId="28">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process4a9ee4eca8" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process2612ca8" />
 </waiter-list>
  </exchangeEvent>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Exchange Events** provide details and context on the deadlock itself. Specifically the `WaitType` **e_waitPipeGetRow** is a resource that one `SELECT` statement owns and another `SELECT` statement is waiting on, ergo being *blocked* by the first `SELECT` (for example due to resource contention). This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3000313/5059085) provides more context on it and deadlocks specifically.

I'm not an expert on reading deadlock graph data, but my research seems to indicate that kind of `WaitType` is potentially related to [**intra-query parallelism deadlocks**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4089473/kb4089473-better-intra-query-parallelism-deadlock-troubleshooting-in-s) (as mentioned in the previously linked StackOverflow answer).

You may find SentryOne's higher level read on [deadlocks](https://www.sentryone.com/sql-server/sql-deadlock) helpful in understanding what's going on.

Comment: I did notice a memorygrant warning on one of the underlying queries involved in the graph.  The stats were out of date on a few tables.   Updated the stats and the warning has gone away.  Waiting to see if it fixes the deadlock or not.

Comment: Note that the presense of intra-query parallel waits in a deadlock graph does not alwasy mean it is an "intra-query parallel thread deadlock".  It could be that one thread of a parallel query is involved in an ordinary deadlock with another session, and other threads in the parallel query are blocked and appear in the deadlock graph.